# about spring mvc using jstl

Tags: spring-mvc, web, jstl

I am trying to use jstl, but on my web page, its not really passing the list I'd like to pass.I was expecting to show the job's detail like id, butI can just get something like:

```
${job.jobId}
```

appear on my web page.
In my controller,

```
@RequestMapping(value="/jobDetail.action")
public ModelAndView jobDetailView() throws DBConnectionException {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    //Map<String, List<Job>> message = new HashMap<String, List<Job>>();
    jobs = jobdao.getAllJobs();
    mav.setViewName("jobDetail");
    mav.addObject("jobs",jobs);
    return mav;
}
```

In the jsp:

```
<table >
    <tr>
        <td>Job Name</td>
        <td>Job Owner</td>
        <td>Description</td>
        <td>Status</td>
    </tr>
    <c:forEach items="${jobs}" var="job">
    <tr>
        <td>${job.jobId}</td>
        <td><c:out value="${job.notifier}"/></td>
        <td><c:out value="${job.description}"/></td>
        <td><c:out value="${job.jobStatus}"/></td>
    </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Could anyone please give me some suggestion? Did I use jstl in the wrong way?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Those `${}` things is EL, not JSTL. Those `<c:xxx>` tags is JSTL.

Comment: Yes. My problem is the attributes of my elements not get shown. So that might because i am not using jstl in the right way?

Comment: What is the output you are seeing? You say "I can just get something like: ${job.jobId} show in my page." - does that work or not? You have not made it clear what your actual problem is...

Comment: not working. I just see ${job.jobId}. It was expected to be the id of the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved. it's because the title in html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

This line makes my include of jstl not visible.

Comment: I'd be very surprised, if that was the direct cause of the problem.